# Embed Google analytics tracking code in shiny app

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny

I have been using Google analytics to track activity on a shiny web app using the following at the top of my `ui.R`:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tags$head(HTML(
        "<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||
        function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();
        a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async=1;
        a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })
        (window, document, 'script',
        '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'XXXXXXX', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>"
      )),
...
)
```

However, I recently registered a new app and the tracking code I get from Google analytics is:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'XXXXX');
</script>
```

Following [RStudio's](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html) instructions I have saved this as `google-analytics.js` and inplace of `tags$head(HTML("..."))` I have:

```
includeScript("google-analytics.js")
```

However this does not work. The instructions from the above link say:

> Warning: the includeScript function places the content of the script inside a pair of script tags . If you copy and paste Javascript code into a .js file be sure to remove these tags

I have experimented with removing `<script>` and `</script>`, as well as the html tags surrounding `async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXX"` but neither work.

Can anyone shed some light on how to get this working properly?

Comment: Have you tried using `includeHTML()` instead?

Comment: fugu: Based on [Step 3 - Embed tracking script](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html), do not use only `includeScript(....)`, use `tags$head(includeScript("google-analytics.js"))` instead

Comment: @parth - OK will give this a go, although it's still not clear to me what I need to remove from my tracking code I get from google analytics. Do i need to remove all `<script>` tags, or just the leading and trailing ones?

Comment: I would guess you can only put the part between the second `<script>...</script>` set into the `.js` file and use `includeScript()` for that. Then I'd leave `<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXX"></script>` in plain `tags$head(HTML("..."))`

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [article](http://douglas-watson.github.io/post/2018-02_shiny_google_analytics/) by Douglas Watson, all you have to do is:

1. Copy the analytics HTML snippet into a text file. (created a file named google_analytics.R, in the same directory as ui.R)
2. Include it in ui.R

   `shinyUI(fluidPage(
     tags$head(includeHTML(("google-analytics.html"))),
     ...`

Comment: I've seen this article before. Is there a typo? I don't see where `google_analytics.R` is referenced. What is `google-analytics.html`?

Comment: I know - that's from the article. What I mean is I don't see how my `server.R` script knows what `google_analytics.R` or `google-analytics.html` are.

Comment: Might be a typo in the article. Try with google-analytics.html instead of .r...

And also, make sure to use includeHTML instead of HTML.